# How to call functions defined in an external C file from a ROS package?

Tags: ros, external-libraries, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a C file(cluster.c) and a header file(cluster.h) which are not a part of any ROS package. I want to call functions in that C file from my already existing ROS package's source file(detect.cpp). Note that "cluster.c" is just a collection of some C functions without a main(). So, it can't be compiled separately.

I thought of  creating a library out of "cluster.c" and "cluster.h" and link that library to my ROS package? How do I do this? What changes should I make to my existing package's CMakeLists.txt and package.xml?

This may be a silly and repeated question as I found similar questions being answered.  As I am very new to ROS I couldn't understand much from those answers. If someone could explain me in simple terms, it would be great.

Thanks,
Raj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186332/how-to-call-functions-defined-in-an-external-c-file-from-a-ros-package?/) by [Keerthi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/8061/keerthi-raj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just add those files as header files like `#include<filename.h>` or `#include<filename.c>`  in your source files in ros package.

Then you can call those functions from the source file.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Keerthi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/8061/keerthi-raj/) on 2014-07-12**:
@Sai, Thank you very much. It was such a simple thing.